# How do I fix this 'no such table' error in my database code?

Tags: python-3.x, database, sqlite

I am trying to run a database for storing certain data. Unfortunately, when I run my code in terminal, it throws an error stating that "no such table: analytics_sessions". What must I do/implement within my code in order to fix this issue.

I already have connected this code to a database file. Nothing is inside the file but it does exist.

This is my python3 code:

```
from ._db import db_connect

   import contextlib


   #
   # Game sessions-- measuring how long players play each of our games        
   # for at a stretch.
   #

   def post_game_session_info(game_id, start_datetime, duration_sec,      user_id):
    # TODO: Procure user_ids so we can link against the 'users' table.
    # TODO: Add client time!
    # TODO: Ensure datetime is stored in UTC.
    with db_connect() as model_db_connection:
        with contextlib.closing(model_db_connection.cursor()) as cursor:
          cursor.execute(
                "insert into analytics_sessions (game_id, start_server_date_time, duration_sec, user_id) "
                "values (?,?,?,?)",
                (game_id, str(start_datetime), duration_sec, user_id)
          )
```

This is the terminal error message that is thrown when I try running the code:

```
 File "/Users/elliotfayman/Documents/GitHub/whale-beta/model/analytics.py", line 19, in post_game_session_info
    (game_id, str(start_datetime), duration_sec, user_id)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: analytics_sessions
```

Comment: First of all format the code, it's unreadable. Check the database connection details such as database name, user, etc. Also, check the user has permission to the table you are trying to insert to. Directly access the database from the console and try to insert, see whether that is happening.

Comment: You say "nothing is inside".  Do you mean that the database has no table schema defined?  Database tables must be created before inserting data into the table.  The `INSERT INTO` statement will not create the table.  First use a `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: Remove several variables from your problem, by switching to SQLite commandline tool (donwloadable for free from their webpage). Create a toy database with identical structure and start trying the queries there. This way you can ignore problems with setting up connections from python and with mistakes you make on pyhton code level. Just "hard code" some examples of what you are trying from code. Also, the toy database would really be helpful here. Post it as some lines of `create ...` and `insert ....` along with an example query which triggers the error you describe ([mcve]).